# Compare id's of objects in two lists and get the list of objects that includes objects with ids occurring in both of them

Tags: c#, linq, collections, compare

I have struggled with it for a long time. I have two collections: MyRepository.All and MyCollection, both holds the collection of objects which has ID property. I need to get result of list of objects from MyRepository.All what contains only objects which id's are equal to MyCollection's objects'ids.

ICollection MyCollection // as parameter to method

```
var result = MyRepository.All.Where(r=>r.id==MyCollection.???.id).ToList();
```

i need to replace ??? with some linq to get this done.
ive tried different where and select caluses, excist and intersect and so on..

Answer (score 9):

```
from a in MyRepository.All
join m in MyCollection on a.Id equals m.Id
select a
```

Answer (score 4):

Cache the ids of MyCollection into a HashSet.
Than you can retrieve your result with a Where clause like this :

```
var myIdSets = new HashSet(MyCollection.Select(c => c.Id));

var result = MyRepository.All.Where(r=> myIdSets.Contains(r.id)).ToList();
```

Comment: Fyi, there's no reason to call `All.Where(...)`; I'm not even sure that is possible without passing in a function. Just call `MyRepository.Where(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = (from r in MyRepository.All
              join r2 in MyCollection on r.id equals r2.id
              select r).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyRepository.All.Where(r=>MyCollection.Select(a=>a.id).Contains(r.id))
```

Comment: I got this errer:Unable to create a constant value of type 'MySolution.MyProject.MyObject'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: var tmpArray = MyCollection.Select(a=>a.id).ToArray();
    MyRepository.All.Where(r=>tmpArray.Contains(r.id))

Answer (score 0):

Linq has an .Intersect that should get you want you need.

Something like this:

var result = MyRepository.Intersect(MyCollection).ToList();

More info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx